# "Growing so much" vs "so much growing"

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sounds better or is more grammatically correct?

> 1. *The frog was hungry from growing so much* **OR**
> 2. *The frog was hungry from so much growing*

Comment: To be safe and keep this open, can you provide your own opinion, or explain why you are unsure or confused? See [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: To me, "growing so much" focuses on the change in size.  "So much growing" focuses on the duration or intensity of the process of growing.

Answer (score 1):

We're missing a lot of context, so it's hard to give anything other than a very general answer.  Neither of them is wrong per se, though the second one is less common.  Particularly with the subject "frog" and the verb "growing", the second one sounds like it would be in a book for small children.